# How to databind checkbox using MYSQL in JSP-Spring MVC

Tags: mysql, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

Under MYSQL

```
CREATE TABLE TINYIMPL(
OID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADDRESS VARCHAR(30),
TYPE VARCHAR(5),
ISACTIVE TINYINT(1),
PRIMARY KEY (`OID`)
);
```

1)How shall The above TINYINT(1) shall be interpreted as a checkbox list in JSP?

2)By default, TYPE is set to type1 in the database, When we click on the check box and on submission of this form in jsp I should get type2.

My jsp code looks like this,

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Logistics Section Welcomes You</title>
    </head> 
<h4>Welcome, ${author}</h4>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h3>TINYIMPL</h3>
        <TABLE BORDER="1">
        <TR>
            <TH>OID</TH>
            <TH>ADDRESS</TH>
            <TH>TYPE</TH>
            <TH>ISACTIVE</TH>
        </TR>
            <c:forEach var="tinyimpl" items="${tinyimpl}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                <td>${tinyimpl.ADDRESS}</td>
                <td>${tinyimpl.TYPE}</td>
                <td>${tinyimpl.ISACTIVE}</td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>             
        </table> 
    </div>
</body>
```

For a data bind between checkbox and mysql,

The problem is to declare a TINYINT and illustrate the same as a CHECKBOX and further updation process to be done when clicked.
Right answer gets Rewarded.

Comment: _Right answer gets Rewarded_??

Comment: @Karna sure +10 +15, do you know the answer

Comment: take a look at what spring controllers are there and spring form data binding tutorials.

Comment: The problem is to declare a TINYINT and illustrate the same as a checkbox and further updation process to be done when clicked